# Class Data Member Inaccessible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

```
int Warrior :: attack ()
{
  int hit;
  srand(time(0));

if (Warrior.weapon == 6)
    int hit = rand() % 5 + 1;
else if (Warrior.weapon == 7)
    int hit = rand() % 7 + 4;
else if (Warrior.weapon == 8)
    int hit = rand() % 7 + 9;
else if (Warrior.weapon == 9)
    int hit = rand() % 7 + 14;
else if (Warrior.weapon == 10)
    int hit = rand() % 7 + 19;

std::cout<< "You hit " << hit <<"!\n";

return hit;
}
```

I get this error: `Error C2059: syntax error : '.'`
(also I know I should use a `switch` statement instead of `else if`)

Thank You.

Comment: It's impossible without seeing your class definition, but you probably want `this->weapon` instead, or, as @chris says, if it's static, `Warrior::weapon`.

Comment: Also, you only need to seed once, not every time you hit.

Comment: You're re-declaring `hit` 5 times. You just want an assignment. Delete the `int` keyword on those lines. And you should call `srand(time(0))` only *once* during the execution of your program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Warrior` is the name of the class. If you are inside of a member function, you do not need to qualify data members with the name of the class. You should also declare `hit` before the chain of if-then-else:

```
int hit;
if (weapon == 6)
    hit = rand() % 5 + 1;
else if (weapon == 7)
    hit = rand() % 7 + 4;
else if (weapon == 8)
    hit = rand() % 7 + 9;
else if (weapon == 9)
    hit = rand() % 7 + 14;
else if (weapon == 10)
    hit = rand() % 7 + 19;
```

You would probably be better off with a `switch` statement, or even an array of pairs for `%` and `+` values.

```
int mod[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,5,7,7,7,7};
int add[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,9,14,19};
int hit = rand() % mod[weapon] + add[weapon];
```

In the arrays above, when `weapon` is, say, 8, the `mod[weapon]` is `7`, and the `add[weapon]` is `9`, matching the data from your `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I will use a switch statement instead.